How to calculate the octahedral distortion parameters from CIF or xyz files of perovskites?
I was trying to know how to calculate the octahedral distortion parameters ($\theta_{tilt}$, $\theta_{in}$, $\theta_{out}$, $\sigma$, D) from CIF or xyz files of perovskites? Is there any example or code you could suggest?
I checked this paper: https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2017/sc/c7sc01590a
It has a supplementary file and a CIF file which has a matlab code (in pages 20-22), which has some hints to calculate those. But I am not fully sure how to implement those to get the mentioned parameter values.
Any simpler example or guidance would be very helpful.

The CIF has several structure on it. At the end of each structure, was added the RES file used in the refinement process with the Olex2 software. For example, the first structure end in line 363 and the RES file is between lines 365 and 470. The MATLAB code is for calculate the PbBrAngles_witherror from the info on the CIF.
